# Location of a maximized window with custom chrome

Tags: windows, winapi

I've created a window with a custom chrome by:

1. Handling `WM_NCHITTEST` and returning the appropriate values for the window caption and borders,
2. Swallowing `WM_NCPAINT` (and `WM_NCUAHDRAWCAPTION`, `WM_NCUAHDRAWFRAME`),
3. Handling `WM_SETTEXT`, `WM_SETICON` and `WM_NCACTIVATE` with `DefWindowProc` by temporarily removing `WM_VISIBLE`,
4. Handling `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` to apply a window region for rounded corners.

Moving/Resizing is handled fine by Windows. I added `WS_THICKFRAME` to the window styles to enable Aero Snap functionality. But now when the window is maximized it is positioned at `(-5,-5)` and my custom titlebar is cut off (this doesn't happen without `WS_THICKFRAME`).

What is the proper way to fix that? What influences that position? It seems to be unrelated to values returned for `WM_NCHITTEST`.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but it seems like noone else has answered.

You can check when the window is maximized and account for the margin when the window is maximized.  You may want to handle WM_NCCALCSIZE rather than WM_NCPAINT to make the entire window appear as client area, rather than painting the non-client area.

This describes one approach to implementing custom chrome (I was the author):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

Hope that helps,